# Why did I get the error 'cannot load external tileset'

Tags: python, pygame, tiled, pytmx

I just want to know how to fix the error that I mention in the title.

I really don't know what to try, there are only 3 lines of code and they are exactly how it's shown in the doc of pytmx...

```py
import pygame
import pytmx

tmxdata = pytmx.TiledMap("map test pygame.tmx")
```

I just want to "load" the map that I create without this HUGE error:

```
Cannot load external tileset: C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\projet\labyrinthe\test pygame tileset.tsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\projet\labyrinthe\testTMX.py", line 4, in <module>
    tmxdata = pytmx.TiledMap("C:/Users/WILHEM/Desktop/brdl Python 3/projet/labyrinthe/carte test pygame.tmx")
  File "C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 360, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(ElementTree.parse(self.filename).getroot())
  File "C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 400, in parse_xml
    self.add_tileset(TiledTileset(self, subnode))
  File "C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 845, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(node)
  File "C:\Users\WILHEM\Desktop\brdl Python 3\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 874, in parse_xml
    raise Exception
Exception
```

If you can help me... Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: Please provide a [example] and include a larger part of the error message.

Comment: What is a "HUGE error"? I don't understand really what you mean by this.

Comment: I guess your filepath is simply wrong.

Comment: I tried every filepath possible, I dont know how it can be wrong.
here is the entire error:

Comment: **I tried every filepath possible** ... no you didn't

Comment: `pytmx.TiledMap` expects a filename to be passed in as argument, not a string with two words before a filename.  Try putting your `pygame.tmx` file in the same folder you are running this script from and change your final line to: `tmxdata = pytmx.TiledMap("pygame.tmx")`

Comment: it doesn't work... sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytmx.util_pygame import load_pygame

load_pygame(filename,pixilalpha=True)
```